# Group By Multiple Column In LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a class like as follows:

```
public class ActualClass
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string IssuerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

It has following data in the table:
[image]

I would like to group them by *IssuerName* and *DateOfIssue* for the following viewModel class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public string IssuerName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
   public List<string> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And data will be displayed as follows: (*Screenshot data will be replaced by the previous table data after successful grouping*)
[image]

**Special attention:** *Is there anything wrong in my ViewModel according to my expectation?*

I tried a lot after following some stackoverflow answers but none did work for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

The code I have tried:

```
var viewmodel = from b in db.BookIssues
                group b by new
                {
                    b.IssuerName,
                    b.DateOfIssue
                }
                into g
                select new ViewModel()
                {
                    Name = g.key.IssuerName,
                    DateOfIssue = g.Key.DateOfIssue,
                    Books = g.ToList() //Actually this line of code is not working
                };
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Books = g.ToList() //Actually this line of is not     working

Probably because **Books** property is type of `List<string>`, not `List<ActualClass>`.

Can you please try this query, I added `b.Select(bn => bn.BookName).ToList()` to extract only names of books:

```
var books = new List<ActualClass>
{
   new ActualClass { BookName = "A", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0), IssuerName = "1" },
   new ActualClass { BookName = "B", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0), IssuerName = "1" },
   new ActualClass { BookName = "C", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0), IssuerName = "1" },
   new ActualClass { BookName = "D", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0), IssuerName = "2" },
   new ActualClass { BookName = "E", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 12, 10, 0), IssuerName = "2" },
   new ActualClass { BookName = "F", DateOfIssue = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 12, 10, 0), IssuerName = "2" }
};

var result = books.GroupBy(x => new { x.IssuerName, x.DateOfIssue })
                .Select(b => new ViewModel
                {
                    Books = b.Select(bn => bn.BookName).ToList(),
                    // Accessing to DateOfIssue and IssuerName from Key.
                    DateOfIssue = b.Key.DateOfIssue,
                    IssuerName = b.Key.IssuerName
                });
```

I grouped by:  `x.IssuerName, x.DateOfIssue`. I did that by passing anonymous type in `GroupBy()` with following manner: `x => new { x.IssuerName, x.DateOfIssue }`.

Now they are in key and you can access to **IssuerName** and **DateOfIssue** from KEY in SELECT statement like in following: `b.Key.IssuerName` and `b.Key.DateOfIssue`.

Comment: Oh!! I did the exactly what you did but unfortunately i mistyped (bn => bn.BookName) as (bn => bn.IssuerName) which I did not noitce !! Thanks A lot..

Answer (score 3):

if you need to select list of books from group result, you need `Books  = v.Select(c=>c.BookName).ToList()` also note that in case of you have time in issue date time you may need to group by only the date part using `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` function. if you only storing date only then you can ignore this function.

```
var viewmodel  = db.BookIssues.GroupBy(x=>new {IssuerName =x.IssuerName, DateOfIssue=EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateOfIssue) })
.Select(v=>new ViewModel(){IssuerName =v.Key.IssuerName, DateOfIssue = v.Key.DateOfIssue, Books  = v.Select(c=>c.BookName).ToList() })
.ToList();
```