# Multiple column group by on Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to use group by on multiple columns however, couldn't understand how should i select the `SAMPLE_TIME` and even if i write Manuel date to sample time I get following error;

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'System.ValueTuple`2[System.String,System.String]' 'System.String'
```

Currently What i use is like below;

```
var dt = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
                          where  dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate
                          group dr1 by ("WAIT_CLASS", "SAMPLE_TIME")  into g
                          select new
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = // How can i select sample_time,
                              WAIT_CLASS = g.Key,
                              WAITS = g.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("WAITS") / 100)
                          }).ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var dt = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
          where  dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate
          group dr1 by new 
                       {
                          WAIT_CLASS = dr1.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),
                          SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")
                       } into g
          select new
                    {
                        SAMPLE_TIME = g.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
                        WAIT_CLASS = g.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
                        WAITS = g.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("WAITS") / 100)
                    }).ToDataTable();
```

Comment: inside of the group by, it throws an error like 'CS0746  C# Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.'

Comment: @doctorcesar: sorry for the mistake, I have updated the post, have a look please

Comment: @doctorcesar: why un-accept? feel free to ask for more clarification if needed

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is create a new anonymous type on group by using group by new and if you want to select you can use your alias. Please check this;
[Group By Multiple Column In LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755567/group-by-multiple-column-in-linq-in-c-sharp)